# Equivalent metrices on unit ball of von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be two faithful, normal states on a von Neumann algebra $M$. Let us define two metrices on the unit ball $M_1$ of $M$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
d_1(x,y):= \rho((x-y)^*(x-y))^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
d_2(x,y):= \sigma((x-y)^*(x-y))^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}
How do we show that the metrices defined above are equivalent ?

N.B. We know that both the metrices induces the strong operator topology on the unit ball. Hence they are topologically equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent metrics if you don't mean topological equivalence?

Comment: On a metric space $X$ two metrices $d_1$ and $d_2$ are considered to be equivalent if there exists $c_1 >0$ and $c_2 >0$ such that $c_1 d_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq c_2 d_1(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't. Let $M=B(H)$. Define trace-class positive injective operators $R,S$ by fixing an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and putting
$$
Re_n=\tfrac1{n^2}\,e_n,\qquad Se_n=\tfrac1{n^4}\,e_n. 
$$
Then define
$$
\rho(x)=\operatorname{Tr}(Rx),\qquad \sigma(x)=\operatorname{Tr}(Sx). 
$$
As $R,S$ are positive an injective, $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are faithful positive linear functionals (that we could normalize to normal states if we needed to). Consider the sequence $\{x_n\}$ given by
$$
x_n=E_n,
$$
where $E_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb C e_n$.
Then
$$
d_1(x_n,0)=\operatorname{Tr}(RE_n)^{1/2}=\frac1{n}, 
$$
while
$$
d_2(x_n,0)=\operatorname{Tr}(SE_n)^{1/2}=\Big(\frac1{n^4}\Big)^{1/2}=\frac1{n^2}.
$$
So the two metrics are not equivalent, since $$\frac{d_1(x_n,0)}{d_2(x_n,0)}=n.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In the above example, $d_1(x_n,0) $ and $d_2(x_n,0)$  should be equal to $Tr(Rn^4E_n)^{1/2}$ and $Tr(Sn^4E_n)^{1/2}$ respectively, and for that reason the trace class operators should be changed accordingly. But, I think this example does not fit into my question. The metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are defined on the unit ball of $M$. But, the operators $x_n$'s are not in there.

Comment: You are right, but the two metrics are still not equivalent in the unit ball.

Comment: Yeah right.. Thanks.. Thanks for you time..